# how to collect all elements that has same value into array with python?

Tags: python, arrays

I am finding the longest path with my data and my code is collecting the longest path in each node.

[image]

```
def dfs(node, adj, dp, vis):

    vis[node] = True

    for i in range(0, len(adj[node])): 

        if not vis[adj[node][i]]: 

            dfs(adj[node][i], adj, dp, vis) 

        dp[node] = max(dp[node], [node] + dp[adj[node][i]], key=lambda x: len(x))


def findLongestPathFromEachNode(adj, n): 

    dp = [[x] for x in range(n)]

    vis = [False] * (n + 1) 

    for i in range(1, n + 1): 

        if not vis[i]: 
            dfs(i, adj, dp, vis) 

    return dp[1:]

n = 6
adj = [[] for i in range(n + 1)] 

addEdge(adj, 1, 2)  
addEdge(adj, 1, 3)  
addEdge(adj, 3, 2)  
addEdge(adj, 2, 4) 
addEdge(adj, 2, 5)
addEdge(adj, 3, 4) 
addEdge(adj, 3, 5)
```

and I got this results

```
In[29]:
paths = findLongestPathFromEachNode(adj, n)
paths

Out[29]:
[[1, 3, 2, 4], [2, 4], [3, 2, 4], [4], [5]]
```

while I expect to see the results as

```
[[1, 3, 2, 4], [1, 3, 2, 5], [2, 4], [2, 5], [3, 2, 4], [3, 2, 5], [4], [5]]
```

due to longest paths in each node are reached to node 5 too.

any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core idea to your question is to store not the single path in `dp` but the array of paths: `dp = [[[x]] for x in range(n)]`.

Then in your `dfs` we will compare our new possibly longer paths with any instance from `dp[node]`. For example with zero index because we can guarantee that it will always exist: `if len(dp[node][0]) < 1 + len(dp[adj[node][i]][0]):` and `elif len(dp[node][0]) == 1 + len(dp[adj[node][i]][0]):`.

Also, we will need to append a node to every new path in the `dp`:

```py
if len(dp[node][0]) < 1 + len(dp[adj[node][i]][0]):
    dp[node] = []
    for path in dp[adj[node][i]]:
        dp[node].append([node] + path)
    elif len(dp[node][0]) == 1 + len(dp[adj[node][i]][0]):
        for path in dp[adj[node][i]]:
            dp[node].append([node] + path)
```

All in all, it will be:

```
def dfs(node, adj, dp, vis):
    vis[node] = True
    for i in range(0, len(adj[node])): 
        if not vis[adj[node][i]]: 
            dfs(adj[node][i], adj, dp, vis) 
        if len(dp[node][0]) < 1 + len(dp[adj[node][i]][0]):
            dp[node] = []
            for path in dp[adj[node][i]]:
                dp[node].append([node] + path)
        elif len(dp[node][0]) == 1 + len(dp[adj[node][i]][0]):
            for path in dp[adj[node][i]]:
                dp[node].append([node] + path)


def findLongestPathFromEachNode(adj, n): 

    dp = [[[x]] for x in range(n)]
    vis = [False] * (n + 1) 

    for i in range(1, n + 1): 

        if not vis[i]: 
            dfs(i, adj, dp, vis) 

    return dp[1:]

n = 6
adj = [[] for i in range(n + 1)] 

addEdge(adj, 1, 2)  
addEdge(adj, 1, 3)  
addEdge(adj, 3, 2)  
addEdge(adj, 2, 4) 
addEdge(adj, 2, 5)
addEdge(adj, 3, 4) 
addEdge(adj, 3, 5)
```

Comment: thank you for your comment, i have studied from your explanation but i would like to ask is it possible to avoid triple blankets? the result is returned as [[[1, 3, 2, 4], [1, 3, 2, 5]],
 [[2, 4], [2, 5]],
 [[3, 2, 4], [3, 2, 5]],
 [[4]],
 [[5]]] due to dp = [[[x]] for x in range(n)] i just wonder it bcuz when i remove 1 pair of the blanket, the error is occurred

Comment: @Sujin I don't think it's possible. You can understand it from the next statements:
1. One path from one vertex to another is represented by a list of level 1. For example: `[2, 4]` or `[3, 2, 4]`.
2. As far as you need to store some paths of the same length you need the list of level 2. For example: `[[2, 4], [2, 5]]` or [[3, 2, 4], [3, 2, 5]]
3. And in result, you need all of your possible paths. That's why triple brackets. For example: `[[[2, 4], [2, 5]], [[3, 2, 4]], [3, 2, 5]]]`.
But you can define your class like `VertexPathes` which will aggregate paths of the same len.